# How do I move all files from one folder to another using the command line?

Tags: command-line

I would like to know how could I move all files from a folder to another folder with a command line.

Let's say I'm in my Downloads folder and there are a 100 files that I would like to move to my Videos folder, without having to write all the files name.

Comment: You're asking about moving `files` but people showing you how to move not only `files` but `folders`as well. Is that OK?

Comment: @Hontvári Levente gave an answer a year ago that seems to be by far the best, clean, simple, and it works.  So how did it get only 3 votes (as compared to 262 for the answer currently at the top)?

Comment: Simple: mv * ~/dir

Answer (score 573):

Open a terminal and execute this command:

```
mv  -v ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos/
```

It will move all the files and folders from Downloads folder to Videos folder.

---

**To move all files, but not folders:**

If you are interested in moving all files (but not folders) from Downloads folder to Videos folder, use this command

```
find ~/Downloads/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Videos
```

**To move only files from the Download folders, but not from sub-folders:**

If you want to move all files from the Downloads folder, but not any files within folders in the Download folder, use this command:

```
find ~/Downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Videos
```

here, `-maxdepth` option specifies how deep find should try, `1` means, only the directory specified in the find command. You can try using `2`, `3` also to test.

See  the Ubuntu [find manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/find.1.html) for a detailed explanation

Comment: you can use mv alone to move an entire directory to another folder: mv folder ~/Documents

Comment: FYI I believe your first command ("mv -v ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos/") won't move dot files.

Comment: Yes, It won't move the .files

Comment: Nb. your `-print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Videos` can be more efficiently done with `-exec mv -t ~/Videos \{\} \+` :-)

Comment: yeah, that's true. I was novice then when i answered the question

Comment: Will this `find ~/Downloads/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Videos` command write over files if two filenames are identical?

Comment: `mv  -v ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos/` does not work for hidden files

Comment: for hidden files trick `folder/.*` (note the dot) works - it says some busy errors, but the move still happens => source: https://askubuntu.com/a/399632

Comment: For anyone else wondering `-v` means "verbose" (it will give you more console output)

Comment: @stevec That's what I just checked and it dosn't make sense to me that the verbose flag allows me to copy all files (I guess they ran out of inspiration)

Comment: I always like to run `-v` for any new git commands to flesh out the sub-steps better.

Comment: NOTE: mv versions works **only** under certain conditions (namely, if length of files is less than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes)

Comment: @DimanNe, exactly, for longer lists you need to send the paths to STDIN somehow

Answer (score 50):

```
mv ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos
```

It will move all the files including subfolders in the directory you want to `mv`. If you want to `cp` (copy) or `rm` (remove) you will need the `-r` (recursive) option to include subfolders.

Comment: My mv command doesn't have a -R option (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: @MarkDoliner, yes, `mv` doesn't need recursive option to include subfolders. One can use it also for renaming.

Comment: I didn't need * . Same thing happened without using the star.

Comment: The ~/ in the prefix of the folder names doesn't always work (doesn't work on bash and git atleast)

Comment: This solution will give an error if the source directory is empty.

Comment: It works **only** under certain conditions (namely, if length of files is less than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes)

Answer (score 44):

For the simple case:

```
mv ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos
```

If you want to move dot (hidden) files too, then set the **dotglob** shell option.

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos
```

This leaves the shell option set.

For one time dotglob use, run the commands in a subshell:

```
(shopt -s dotglob; mv ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos)
```

Comment: A note for myself: The last option `(shopt -s dotglob; mv ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos)` *only* moves (cuts) the contents (including the hidden files). In this case, both the origin and destination folders must exist already. At the end, the origin directory becomes empty.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: It works **only** under certain conditions (namely, if length of files is less than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes)

Comment: Yes. On Ubuntu 20.04 getconf ARG_MAX is 2MiB. Therefore this method works if there are less than about 250,000 files in the directory.

Comment: ~/Downloads/* No such file or directory

Answer (score 22):

It's possible by using `rsync`, for example:

```
rsync -vau --remove-source-files src/ dst/
```

where:

> `-v`, `--verbose`:               Increase verbosity.
>
> `-a`, `--archive`:               Archive mode; equals `-rlptgoD` (no `-H`, `-A`, `-X`).
>
> `-u`, `--update`:                Skip files that are newer on the receiver.
>
> `--remove-source-files`        This tells **`rsync` to remove from the sending side the files** (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

If you've root privileges, prefix with `sudo` to override potential permission issues.

Comment: WARNING! the --delete-after option as noted doesn't work the way you might expect.  It doesn't delete the *source* files after successful copy... IT DELETES ALL THE REMAINING/OTHER FILES IN THE DESTINATION.  (as @kenorb noted... but I didn't read carefully enough! DOH)

Comment: This warning can be ignored / should be removed as the author corrected his answer.

Answer (score 10):

To move a directory with or without content to its new name just like how you would use the `mv` command to rename a file:

`mv -T dir1 dir2`

where:

- `-T` treats the destination as a normal file
- `dir1` is the original name of the directory
- `dir2` is the new name of the directory

NB: `dir2` doesn't have to exist.

I hope this saves someone a lot of time, as a noob, before this, I would create a directory with the new name and then move the contents of the directory to the directory created earlier.

**Use for subdirectories**

This command is useful when many files have been saved in a subfolder of the target directory i.e. `Downloads/mp4`. In this example, running `mv -T Downloads/mp4 Videos` will result in `mp4` subfolder being *removed* and all files contained inside are moved to Videos folder.

Comment: +1 because tested working in Xubuntu 14.04. I have added an example in this answer to show that this command will cause the `dir1` to be removed. Aside from this precaution, this answer has noted something good for daily use.

Comment: "To move a directory with or without content to its new name" How can you move a directory...to a name? That makes no sense. "-T treats the destination as a normal file" How can a destination be a file? Do you mean directory?

Comment: Its like renaming a file to its new name like you would do with something like `mv fileA fileB` but the `-T` flag in this case treats the destination/directory as a file and renames it.

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This option works well when you need to move the contents of directories unreadable by the current user, using `sudo`. In other answers with globs, the glob expands before sudo sees it, and since the directory is unreadable, the glob expands to nothing.
Note however that BSD `mv` (OSX) doesn't seem to have this option.

Comment: For those who are slow like me, *this command is simply renaming the directory*. And since `mv` overwrites the target by default, it will silently overwrite the target dir. So this will only work if the target is nonexisting or empty, otherwise you will lose data in the target.

Answer (score 6):

```
mv source_path/* destination_path/
```

here you have to put forward slash and `*` after source path so that it will take files inside source_path instead of the complete source directory.

Example: `mv /home/username/test/*  /home/username/test2/`

The above command moves all files (unless they are hidden) in the source directory to the destination directory.

Comment: It works **only** under certain conditions (namely, if length of files is less than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes)

Comment: It was not so complicated. Thx. The best answer with no doubt

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
mv -v ~/rootfolder/branch/* ~/rootfolder
```

I hope this helps. Because I had the same pain and wasted a lot of time fixing my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the command line and get into the directory you want to move it to with `cd folderNamehere`
2. Type `pwd`. This will print the directory you want to move it too.
3. Then change to the directory where all of the files are with `cd folderNamehere`
4. Now to move all the files type `mv *.* typeAnswerFromStep2here`

That will move all files from that directory to the other.

Comment: This will not match files without any extension. for example if a folder has the files: `foo.txt`, `bar.` and `bar` both `bar.` and `bar` will not be moved. Using `*` instead of `*.*` takes care of that. But in both cases, hidden files like: `.foobar` will not be moved.

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
find ~/Desktop -type f -iname  "*.mp4" -exec mv {} ~/Videos \;
```

**-type**
with the argument -type you can specify type file.on this statement that is the mean file.if using of -d that means directory.

**-iname:**
the most common and obvious method to look for a file is using its -name argument.if you  are not sure about its case-sensitivity you can use of -iname argument

**mv {}**
and finally to specify target directory and then moving the files on there using mv {} argument

Answer (score 1):

This command should do it:

```
sudo find ~/Downloads -mindepth 1 -prune -exec mv '{}' ~/Videos \;
```

It moves all visible and hidden files, and doesn't throw unnecessary errors, not even if the source directory is empty.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy all contents using `rsync` and remove all files using `--remove-source-files` remove copied directories using `find -type d | rm` :

```
rsync -auv  --remove-source-files ./src ./dst \
&& find ./dst -type d | sed -n '1d;p' | xargs rm -rf -
```

The command `sed -n '1d;p'` excludes first directory path from the directories listed, since the first directory in the list is directory **dst** itself!

OR you can run all in a single command (Thanks to good muslim @muru):

```
find  ./dst -mindepth 1 -type d -delete
```

Comment: You don't need all that. `-mindepth 1` with `find` will exclude `dst` from the matched list. `find` itself has the `-delete` action for deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add one more answer. If you are already in the folder you want to move files out of, you can do this:

```
mv * ~/Videos
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of this existing answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/387727

Comment: @karel This answer is intended to cover the case "If you are already in the folder you want to move files out of" and the command it shows is accordingly different from the command in [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/387727/22949). Whether or not one considers it useful to have an answer covering this case, this answer is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Thanks for the backup @Eliah Kagan

Comment: It works **only** under certain conditions (namely, if length of files is less than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes)