# How can I get mv (or the * wildcard) to move hidden files?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am migrating my home directory from an old system to a new one, and the tarball I made contains everything, including hidden files like .bashrc. However, when I move the contents of the unpacked tarball (which are in /tmp) to my new home directory, the hidden files do not copy (`mv /tmp/home/rcook/* /home/rcook/`). How can I get mv to move them?

Actually, I think the problem is not with mv, but with bash's globbing. If I do this:

```
mkdir a
mkdir b
touch a/.foo
touch a/bar
mv a/* b/
ls -a a/ b/
```

I see this:

```
a/:
.  ..  .foo

b/:
.  ..  bar
```

`a/.foo` did not move. So how can I get the * wildcard to find hidden files?

Yes, I suppose I could decompress the tarball directly into my home directory, but the tarball decompresses into `home/rcook/...`, and I want to be sure I overwrite the new `.bashrc`, etc. with the old, customized versions, and knowing how to find and move hidden files is a worthwhile skill. Suggestions?

---

Some answers suggest doing something like `mv src/.* dest/`. However, I tried this on my test directories and got errors. Starting with:

```
rcook$ ls -a a/ b/
a/:
.  ..  bar  .foo

b/:
.  ..
rcook$ mv a/.* b/
mv: cannot move 'a/.' to 'b/.': Device or resource busy
mv: cannot remove 'a/..': Is a directory
rcook$ ls -a a/ b/
a/:
.  ..  bar

b/:
.  ..  .foo
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251091/139312

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You can do this :

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv /tmp/home/rcook/* /home/rcook/
```

You can put

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

in your `~/.bashrc` if you want it to be the default.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

---

Another approach to copy the dot files:

```
mv /tmp/home/rcook/.[!.]* /home/rcook/
```

Don't use the pattern `..*` as it matches `..` (pointer to the parent directory). If there are files whose name begin with two dots (`..something`), also use the pattern `..?*`.

Comment: Please check out the additions I put at the bottom of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Nothings wrong, `.` and `..` are specials dirs : respectively _current dir_ & _parent dir_. It's just a warning. Better use `shopt -s dotglob` solution

Comment: I ended up just doing two moves: `mv home/rcook/* /home/rcook/` followed by `mv home/rcook/.* /home/rcook/`. This did the trick, though I wish I had followed the link and read about dotglob mode first. It would have saved me a step. +1

Comment: So the second approach requires the use of absolute paths?

Comment: No, you can do it in a relative way.

Comment: @sputnick please edit your post with the additional infos from your comments and delete the comments afterwards.

Comment: If you're using `zsh`, you can use [the `D` globbing qualifier](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89771/3587) or [the `GLOB_DOTS` shell option](http://superuser.com/a/373751/70130).

Comment: Wouldn't the second approach exclude any files with a dot in them later on, eg "myfile.txt"?

Comment: No,  `.[!.]*` is : a dot, followed by **anything but a dot**, followed by anythings

Comment: shopt -s dotglob = best solution of all

Comment: mv won't try to do things with . or .., but other commands will.  Especially chown and chmod.  Knowing `.[!.]?` or the like will definitely prevent mistakes.

Comment: You have reason, working this: mv /tmp/home/rcook/.[!.]* /home/rcook/

Answer (score 72):

In your additions, you got errors but the code still worked. The only thing to add is that you told it *only* to copy the dot files. Try:

```
mv src/* src/.* dst/
```

You will still get the errors for the . and .. entries, which is fine. But the move should succeed.

```
~/scratch [andrew] $ mv from/* from/.* to/
mv: cannot move ‘from/.’ to ‘to/.’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot remove ‘from/..’: Is a directory
~/scratch [andrew] $ ls -a from/ to/
from/:
.  ..

to/:
.  ..  test  .test
```

Comment: Good points,  @AndrewSchwartz. I like this approach, too. I think it deserves more recognition.

Comment: I like @Drake Clarris answer a little more, because I'm running on Amazon AWS CodeBuild and the non zero return code actually caused my build to stop. I ended up moving the one `.hidden` file I had explicitly to solve my problem though.

Comment: If the non-zero exit code is a problem you could suppress it, e.g. by appending `|| :` (`||` means execute the following on false/error, `:` is noop command). But that would suppress legit errors too, e.g. destination folder does not exist. I can't find a more elegant way using `mv` to exclude the `.` and `..` entries. Butt big plus for me over cp is not writing new files to disk.

Answer (score 17):

If you `ls -l` in a directory, you will see `.` and `..` among listed files. So, I think `mv .* /dest` takes those pointers into account. Try:

```
mv /tmp/home/rcook/{*,.[^.]*,..?*} /home/rcook/
```

this will ignore those current and parent dir pointers.

You will get an error if any of the three patterns `*`, `[^.]*` or `..?*` matches no file, so you should only include the ones that match.

Comment: Nice.  A similar answer for this style of globbing is here: http://superuser.com/a/784046/144977 . Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 12):

Two possible solutions I can think of. The first is to use cp instead with its recursive option, copying the current directory to the destination.

```
cp -Rp . /desired/directory
```

then you can remove the source files in the current directory

Alternatively, if you know the files are sanely named (no spaces, wildcards, non-printable characters), you can do something like this

```
mv $(ls -A) /desired/directory
```

Comment: Copy-then-remove is very different from move if the source and target are on the same filesystem. At least include the option `-p` to preserve metadata. Using `ls` should be a last resort, and here there are better, simpler ways.

Comment: this is good solution so far

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but, one simple way to do it is:

```
mv a/{.*,*} b/
```

### Explanation

This is called **brace expansion**. In this case, the shell expands the path you give by concatenating the string given before the braces (in this case `a/`) followed by each variation given in the list surrounded by the braces.
The variation list is composed by values separated by commas and, again, surrounded by curly braces. So, in this case we have `.*` and `*` as elements, so the list must be `{.*,*}`.

```
mv a/{.*,*} b/
```

The above expression can be read this way: move all files starting with a dot (`.*`) **AND** anything else (`*`) in the `a/` directory to the `b/` directory.

### More hints

This is very helpful and can be used in various scenarios. For example, imagine you have to create 100 files with the following naming pattern: file1, file2, file3...file100. You can easily achieve it by doing this

```
touch file{1..100}
```

In this case, you can see a **range** was given. You can do this by separating the first and last values by two dots (`..`).

### Going Beyond!

I'm new to the Unix world and, even knowing this works in `bash` and `zsh` (the shells I've used so far), I can't guarantee this will work in any shell.

You can see more about **expansions** an **globbing** in your shell's documentation (using: `man bash` or `man zshall`, for bash and zsh respectively).

Hope this helps future readers!

Comment: If you write it like `{*,.*}`, it's also an emoji

Comment: This is a really elegant solution and I think it should be upvoted more.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really such a thing as "hidden" files on Linux. Files which begin with a dot are just hidden from file listings by default.

To copy files even with a glob, you need to prefix the file with `.` such as `mv -u .* foo` and then `.foo` will appearn as `foo/.foo` when moved.

The -u option will only move the files when the source is newer, or the destination is missing. Or you could just ignore the errors about moving `.` and `..` as they are special files and cannot be moved, but do get caught in the `.*` glob by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

So we have:

```
a
|-- .foo
`-- bar
```

and:

```
b
```

---

I took a **huge** time finding better solution than all the answers here.

Then I took **30 seconds** for this command:

```
$ mv --help
```

Then I found my love:

```
$ mv a/ b/ -T
```

Note: I don't even understand the argument `-T`. It just did what I needed. Here it says:

> -T, --no-target-directory  treat DEST as a normal file

Comment: If you omit the slashes, you shouldn't need `-T`.  Either way this is essentially telling mv to move the directory itself, rather than moving all the files from inside it.

Comment: @thomasrutter, isn't moving the directory itself the same thing as renaming it?

Comment: Yes, if the parent destination remains the same, it's essentially just renaming it.  However you refer to it, it probably doesn't help answer the original question, which was about moving the files *inside* the directory into a given location.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was simply trying to `mv` a single hidden file and this was the solution:

```
FILE=.myHiddenFile
mv "$FILE" dest/
```

**Explanation**

At first I was trying:

```
mv .myHiddenFile dest/
```

But it kept producing the error:

```
mv: cannot stat '.myHiddenFile': No such file or directory
```

Even though a `ls -al` showed that the file and `dest/` existed.

The reason appears to be because the shell was interpreting the "." in the file name, so by moving it to a variable it avoids the interpretation. There are probably other ways to resolve this, but this was enough for us.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is to use (GNU) `find`:

```
find /tmp/home/rcook/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} /home/rcook/ \;
```