# confusion of space allocation /home and /HOME

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, home-directory

I recently got a new W8 computer and followed [this](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html) tutorial to get Ubuntu installed in dual boot.
This is what my file system looks like:

```
Device        Directory      Total
/dev/sda6     /               45GBiB
/dev/sda2     /boot/efi       356MiB
/dev/sda7     /HOME           874.3GiB
```

Now, I was going about my data science stuff and downloaded a 12GB file, and un-zipped it. I start getting errors saying that I do not have enough memory. I know I have ~1TB allocated to Linux.
All I can tell is that I was working in /Home/myusername assuming that that's where most of my space was allocated, but it seems as though ~800GB are in /HOME. Since I'm new to Linux I'm a little confused. Any ideas on how to go about this? Should I just start using /HOME or is there a proper way to reallocate space?

Comment: - /home should be in lowercase, not in capitals.
- do a `df -h` and check the free space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Linux file system is case sensitive. You have defined a mountpoint at `/HOME` when instead, you should have used `/home`. Therefore, the `/HOME` is simply not used, it is not your actual home directory, that is in `/home/username` which is completely separate from `/HOME`.

To fix this and use the 874G partition you have created as your actual home directory (in the Linux world, your home dir is referred to as `$HOME` (note the `$`) or `~/`), you will need to follow these steps:

1. Create your home directory on `/HOME`:

   ```
   sudo mkdir "/HOME/$USER"
   sudo chown username "/HOME/$USER"
   ```
2. Copy everything from your current `$HOME` to this new directory.

   ```
   mv ~/* ~/.* "/HOME/$USER"
   ```
3. Tell the system to mount the partition of `/HOME` in the right place, `/home`. For this, you will need to edit `/etc/fstab`:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   That will bring up an editor window, you need to find the line that mounts `/HOME`, it will look something like this:

   ```
   UUID=123-ABC    /HOME   ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0   0
   ```

   Change `/HOME` to `/home`, leave everything else as it is.
4. Remove your home dir and reboot

   ```
   sudo rmdir "/home/$USER"
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: please user $USER instead of username ;-) the system will tranform it to the current user and commands then actually work.

Comment: And that copy command will not work either, use find or rsync

Comment: @bodhi.zazen why not? Changed to `mv` to simplify but the `cp` would get everything. Note that I'm using `-r` and also specifying `~/.*`.

Comment: I get a rmdir: failed to remove `/home/$USER': Directory not empty. What should I do?

Comment: @user263961 means you did not move the contents over. If you are sure about removing it add a `-r` (for recursive delete)

Comment: @user263961 see updated answer, I changed the 2nd step, try that instead.

Comment: @terdon is misses files , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/259383/how-can-i-get-mv-or-the-wildcard-to-move-hidden-files

Comment: I would not delete the old home directory until you make sure everything has been copied.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen as I said, I am using `~/.*` for exactly that reason. The post you linked to was using `*` alone which does not expand to dotfiles but `~/.*` does. `cp ~/* ~/.* target/` will copy everything including hidden files.

Comment: With the new stp 2. I now start getting a series of mv: cannot remove `/home/.../file.csv': Permission denied

Comment: @user263961 that's strange, what is the exact command you are running? You should be the owner of all files in your `$HOME`. Anyway, try `sudo mv ~/* ~/.* "/HOME/$USER"` instead. Also note, that this command moves the files. That means it will 1) copy and 2) remove the original. The errors you are getting are only about 2), the copy should have worked regardless.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen in fact, even the post you linked to mentions this. Could you please delete your comments since they are misleading?

Comment: Ok, this went through and all seems to work just great. Thanks!

Comment: I am a bit old-schooled, but I prefer (as root) `tar cf - . | (cd /dest/dir; tar xvpf -)` for massive copies. It will maintain (possible) different-owned files, mod times, and do the correct thing even for special files. Probably overkill in this case, but...

Comment: @Rmano yes, that is better (+1) but given that this is a new install and an inexperienced user, I tried to keep things simple.

Comment: The `mv` command is likely to cause problems if run as the user whose directory you're moving; it's like trying to move the foundation of a house. This would be fine if you create another account and, within it, issue the `mv` command using `sudo`, though. On many distributions I'd use `root` for this purpose, but Ubuntu makes it impossible to log into the `root` account by default. You either need to activate `root` as a login account (thus violating the Ubuntu security model) or use a third account for this purpose.