# Copy (or move) some files with their parent dirs

Tags: command-line, bash

I have 2-3 levels and several folders but in all is a file with the name `L_data.txt` (among other files). I would like to copy only those `L_data.txt` together with their parent folders without any of the other files to another place. How can I do that?

E.g.:

```
./PycharmProjects/folderA/L_data.txt
./PycharmProjects/folderB/L_data.txt
.
.
./PycharmProjectsCluster/folderQ/L_data.txt
./PycharmProjectsCluster/folderR/L_data.txt
.
.
```

I have found this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/658075/how-do-i-move-files-out-of-nested-subdirectories-into-another-folder-in-ubuntu) and this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172629/how-do-i-move-all-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-the-command-line) but that moves all files **without** the folders. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s say I want a copy of each `L_data.txt` in `new_dir` with its parents preserved. Here is my directory structure right now:

```
$ tree
.
├── new_dir
├── PycharmProjects
│   ├── folderA
│   │   ├── foo.txt
│   │   └── L_data.txt
│   └── folderB
│       ├── foo.txt
│       └── L_data.txt
└── PycharmProjectsCluster
    └── folderQ
        ├── foo.txt
        └── L_data.txt

6 directories, 6 files
```

You can see that I have two file in each directory, `L_data.txt` and `foo.txt`.

We can use `find` command to find all files named `L_data.txt`. Then using its `--exec` option we will run `cp --parents` so it copies the files into the new destination while keeping their parents.

```
find . -name L_data.txt -exec cp --parents -t new_dir/ {} +
```

The result:

```
$ tree new_dir/
new_dir/
├── PycharmProjects
│   ├── folderA
│   │   └── L_data.txt
│   └── folderB
│       └── L_data.txt
└── PycharmProjectsCluster
    └── folderQ
        └── L_data.txt

5 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but for some reason, it does not work. Listing the files as ```find . -name L_data.txt``` works but when I use the full command, it freezes and does not copy.

Comment: EDIT: it works if levels are only 2 but not 3.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example that does not work.

Comment: ```find . -name L_data.txt -exec cp --parents -t new_dir/ {} \;``` instead of the proposed seems to work. Then I have another problem with the ```find``` itself with which I do not want to spam here. Thanks again.