# Im trying to move a file between my home folder to the certs folder

Tags: 20.04

I'm using this command:

```
sudo mv /home/az_123/ubuntue.pem
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
mv: missing destination file operand after '/home/az_123/ubuntue.pem' Try 'mv --help' for more information
```

Comment: So what's the problem - apart from missing the destination in the command?

Comment: I'm not able to shift the file to the respective folder. The following error                        
   mv: missing destination file operand after '/home/az_123/ubuntue.pem'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: You need to include the destination like this: `sudo mv /home/az_123/ubuntue.pem <destination>`. Did you try `mv help` then?

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172629/how-do-i-move-all-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-the-command-line/172634#172634

Comment: Thank so much.May I also know how to copy paste in it?

Answer (score 0):

`mv` needs you to define both a source and a destination. You're getting an error because you did not enter a path for the destination.

Use the following syntax:

```
sudo mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```